# how to print the content of a c++ function argument given such information

Tags: c++, c++11, ros

I have a c++11 code which has a function like the following:

```
bool prepareSwitch(const std::list<hardware_interface::ControllerInfo>& start_list,
                   const std::list<hardware_interface::ControllerInfo>& stop_list)
```

for debugging this code, I'd like to investigate/print for example the `start_list`, however, having a quite basic experience in c++ has made this confusing for me. Yet, the additional information that I can have about this input argument is about `<hardware_interface::ControllerInfo>` the described [in this documentation.](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/hardware_interface/html/c++/structhardware__interface_1_1ControllerInfo.html)

I'm not sure how to use this information to print or investigate this input. Can someone guide a little about it?

using `std::cout <<  start_list << std::endl;` gave a compilation error.

Comment: You need a loop: `for (const auto& controllerInfo : startList) {}`. I don't know if `ControllerInfo` can be displayed as-is though.

Answer (score 1):

To ease debugging you can overload the following operators. (adapt the formatting as needed)

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const hardware_interface::InterfaceResources &ir)
{
  os << "hi: " << ir.hardware_interface << std::endl;
  for (const auto & r : ir.resources)
  {
     os << "r: "<< r << std:;endl;
  }
  return os
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const hardware_interface::ControllerInfo &ci)
{
  os << "name:" << ci.name << std::endl;
  os << "type: " << ci.type<< std::endl;
  for (const auto & cr : ci.claimed_resources)
  {
     os << "cr: " << cr << std::endl;
  }
  return os
}
```

Then you can print your functions arguments:

```
for (const auto& ci: startList) 
{
   std::cout << ci;
}
```